# Proof of convergence implication

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to show that if $(Z_t)_{t> 0}$ is a stochastic process the following implication holds
$$
P(sup_{0<s\le t} |Z_s| > \alpha ) \stackrel{t\to 0}{\to} 0 \Rightarrow Z_t \stackrel{t\to 0}{\to} 0 \ a.s.
$$
 I am really clueless. Any hint / help is appreciated.

Comment: As stated, it is not true, as $Z_t$ can remain larger than $\alpha/2$ for ever and ever without violating the assumption yet without getting the result. You should take more care in copying your homework problems if you want other people to solve them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so we can deduce there exists a deterministic sequence $t_n$ for which the following holds:
$$
P(\underbrace{\sup_{0\le s\le t_n}|Z_s|}_{X_n}>\tfrac{1}{n})\le \tfrac{1}{n^2}
$$
Now, Borel Cantelli yields that almost surely $X_n\le \tfrac{1}{n}$ for $n$ big enough. That should do that job, I think...

Comment: ..like a boss !